# How to wait until ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll finishes before executing more code

Tags: vba, excel

I have a subroutine that calls `ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll` to bring new data in from an XML source on a website, and then performs multiple modifications to it. The problem is that not enough time is given for the `RefreshAll` command to finish, so the following subs and functions end up not executing correctly, which result in repeated rows not being correctly erased.

I have tried using `Application.Wait` and the `Sleep` function, but they seem to pause the refresh process too. I simply want the rest of the code to wait until the refresh process finishes before executing the rest of the code.

Right now I was only able to fix it by not calling on `RefreshAll`, which gives me the idea of implementing a second flow to be executed afterwards, but that's not a good workaround.

According to http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/564959-execute-code-after-data-connection-refresh-finished.html, XML connections do not have a `BackgroundQuery` boolean. That option is only available for ODBC and OLEDB connections, which are types `xlConnectionTypeODBC` and `xlConnectionTypeOLEDB`, respectively. The XML connection I am using is of type `xlConnectionTypeXMLMAP`.

This code is the macro that is recorded when I do this via the UI (including unchecking the "Enable background refresh" in the table properties):

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("XMLTable")
        .Name = "XMLTable"
        .Description = ""
End With
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("XMLTable").refresh
```

The class `ActiveWorkbook.Connections` does NOT have a `BackgroundQuery` option so that I can set it to False.

How can I force my subsequent code to wait until `RefreshAll` finishes?

Answer (score 83):

I had the same issue with an OLEDBConnection connection type, however `DoEvents` (as suggested in a prior answer) didn't help me as my data connections had background-refresh enabled. Instead, using [Wayne G. Dunn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2895550/wayne-g-dunn)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083668/how-to-wait-until-activeworkbook-refreshall-finishes-before-executing-more-code/22085922#22085922) as a jumping-off point, I created the following solution, which worked:

```
Sub Refresh_All_Data_Connections()
    
    For Each objConnection In ThisWorkbook.Connections
        'Get current background-refresh value
        bBackground = objConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery
        
        'Temporarily disable background-refresh
        objConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
        
        'Refresh this connection
        objConnection.Refresh
        
        'Set background-refresh value back to original value
        objConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = bBackground
    Next
    
    MsgBox "Finished refreshing all data connections"
    
End Sub
```

The **MsgBox** is for testing only and can be removed once you're happy the code waits.

Also, I prefer **ThisWorkbook** to **ActiveWorkbook** as I know it will target the workbook where the code resides, just in case focus changes.  Nine times out of ten this won't matter, but I like to err on the side of caution.

However, note that because this uses `BackgroundQuery`, this will not work if you are using an `xlConnectionTypeXMLMAP` connection, sorry.

Comment: This worked for me, but using `ODBCConnection` instead of `OLEDB`.

Comment: This didn't worked for me says run time error 1004 Application defined or object defined error

Comment: I too was getting the run time error 1004, but I was trying the suggestion of changing OLEDBConnection to ODBCConnection per @Dan, since I am using an ODBC DSN.  That produced the 1004 error though.  Then I realized that when you create ODBC connections in more modern versions of Excel, it actually saves it as an OLEDBConnection.  So I used the original code and it worked just fine.

Comment: This works, but means refreshing each connection sequentially which is a lot slower. Would be great if there was a way to refresh concurrently and wait till they're all finished.

Answer (score 25):

This is probably caused by background refresh.

To change the setting, go to Connections and select Properties. On the Usage tab, **uncheck** the "Enable background refresh" checkbox to disable background refresh.

[image: a screenshot showing the described checkbox]

Answer (score 10):

**DISCLAIMER: The code below reportedly caused some crashes! Use with care.**

According to [this 2015 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222091/refresh-both-the-external-data-source-and-pivot-tables-together-within-a-time-sc/30475437#30475437) by [Ejaz Ahmed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2391873/ejaz-ahmed), in Excel 2010 and above `CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone` halts macros until refresh is done:

```
ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone
```

Comment: This caused my excel to crash. AsyncQueries are usually related to refreshes on cube data.

Comment: So far, I've only used this for non-cube PowerQuery refreshes from a SQL server. It worked fine as long as the queries were **not** set to refresh in the background. (w/ excel 2016). Otherwise, it would randomly crash.

Answer (score 6):

You must turn off "background refresh" for all queries.  If background refresh is on, Excel works ahead while the refresh occurs and you have problems.

Data > Connections > Properties > (uncheck) enable background refresh

Comment: I was trying to copy/paste data from one tab to another after a data refresh. The paste kept coming up blank, but after disabling "background refresh" it's working perfectly. Thanks @tim.s

Comment: This might have other implications that go with it.  But for what I was trying to accomplish, it works great.  Thanks

Comment: This repeats the answer from two months prior by subro: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37992044/revisions

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution from 2010 from the MrExcel.com thread, [*Fails: ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll BackgroundQuery:=False*](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/510011-fails-activeworkbook-refreshall-backgroundquery-%3Dfalse.html), by user [p45cal](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/members/p45cal.131933/):

> Either:
> have all the pivotcaches' backgroundquery properties set to False, or
> loop through all the workbook's pivotcaches:
>
> ```
> For Each pc In ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches
>      pc.BackgroundQuery = False
>      pc.Refresh
>  Next
> ```
>
> this will leave all pivotcaches backgroundquery properties as false. You could retain each one's settings with:
>
> ```
> For Each pc In ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches
>     originalBGStatus = pc.BackgroundQuery
>     pc.BackgroundQuery = False
>     pc.Refresh
>     pc.BackgroundQuery = originalBGStatus
> Next
> ```
>
> (all untested)

Comment: Is there something that I have to enable in order to use this? I'm getting a 1004 error at the line `pc.BackgroundQuery = False`
I should also mention that the data is not being imported directly into a pivot. It's been imported into a table, which then a pivot table feeds off of. Does this still work for this case?

Comment: Now I should mention that when I go to the Data tab and then click on Connections and then pick my XML connection (hosted on website) and click properties, I have the "Enable background refresh" UNCHECKED. Is that the same thing as BackgroundQuery?

Comment: You have the correct setting - you do not want the refresh to run in the background. Re 'not directly into a pivot... feeds off..' I'm guessing that still counts.  Also, please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19916824/excel-2013-1004-runtime-error-refresh-query-table-backgroundquery-false

Comment: Mine is a web query, nothing related to SQL. It basically goes to a website where an XML is hosted and imports it into a table. Nothing more or less. The problem is that it doesn't wait for the import to finish. I tried recording a macro when doing the refresh AND unchecking the "Enable background refresh" and the results were interesting. There is no BackgroundQuery option for the subclass I'm using. Read the OP for an update.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
ActiveWorkbook.refreshall
ActiveWorkbook.Save
```

When you save the workbook it's necessary to complete the refresh.

Comment: this one gives me a popup: "This will cancel a pending data refresh. Continue?"

Answer (score 1):

Try executing:

```
ActiveSheet.Calculate
```

I use it in a worksheet in which control buttons change values of a dataset. On each click, Excel runs through this command and the graph updates immediately.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be ideal, but try using "Application.OnTime" to pause execution of the remaining code until enough time has elapsed to assure that all refresh processes have finished.

What if the last table in your refresh list were a faux table consisting of only a flag to indicate that the refresh is complete? This table would be deleted at the beginning of the procedure, then, using "Application.OnTime," a Sub would run every 15 seconds or so checking to see if the faux table had been populated. If populated, cease the "Application.OnTime" checker and proceed with the rest of your procedure.

A little wonky, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

For me, "BackgroundQuery:=False" did not work alone
But adding a "DoEvents" resolved problem

```
.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
VBA.Interaction.DoEvents
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create additional Excel file. It can be even empty.
Or you can use any other existing Excel file from your directories.

'Start'

```
Workbooks.Open("File_where_you_have_to_do_refresh.xlsx")
Workbooks("File_where_you_have_to_do_refresh.xlsx").RefreshAll

Workbooks.Open("Any_file.xlsx)
'Excell is waiting till Refresh on first file will finish'
Workbooks("Any_file.xlsx).Close False

Workbooks("File_where_you_have_to_do_refresh.xlsx").Save
```

or use this:

```
Workbooks("File_where_you_have_to_do_refresh.xlsx").Close True
```

It's working properly on all my files.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick that has worked for me when some lines of VBA code have trouble executing because preceding lines haven't completed doing their thing.  Put the preceding lines in a Sub.  The act of calling the Sub to run those lines may help them finish before subsequent lines are executed.  This trick has helped me with timing issues using the Windows clipboard.

Answer (score -1):

I was having this same problem, and tried all the above solutions with no success.  I finally solved the problem by deleting the entire query and creating a new one.

The new one had the exact same settings as the one that didn't work (literally the same query definition as I simply copied the old one).

I have no idea why this solved the problem, but it did.

Answer (score -1):

If you're not married to using Excel Web Query, you might try opening the URL as a separate Workbook instead.  Going that route lets you work on the resulting data once the web request completes, just like if you turn off "Enable background refresh."

The nice thing is though, Excel displays a progress bar during the request, instead of just freezing up / showing a load message in the destination cell.

See my answer on this question: [How can I post-process the data from an Excel web query when the query is complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32974553/how-can-i-post-process-the-data-from-an-excel-web-query-when-the-query-is-comple/32974554#32974554)

The tradeoff of that approach is you have to manage processing the data you get back yourself - Excel won't put it in a given destination for you.

We ended up going this route after we tried something pretty similar to what you seem to have been doing.

Answer (score -1):

I tried a couple of those suggestions above, the best solution for me was to disable backgroundquery for each connection.

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - DL_3").OLEDBConnection
    .BackgroundQuery = False
    End With
```

Answer (score -1):

I have had a similar requirement. After a lot of testing I found a simple but not very elegant solution (not sure if it will work for you?)...

After my macro refresh's the data that Excel is getting, I added into my macro the line "Calculate" (normally used to recalculate the workbook if you have set calculation to manual).

While I don't need to do do this, it appears by adding this in, Excel waits while the data is refreshed before continuing with the rest of my macro.