# Refreshing and Saving as a text file in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, powerquery

I have been trying to automatically refresh my table (obtained from an SQL database via power query) and directly save it as a text file (tab delimited)
I'm very new with VBA and the macro i used is

```
    Public Sub UpdatePowerQueries()
 'Macro to update the Power Query script(s) and save the file as .txt

Dim cn As WorkbookConnection

For Each cn In ThisWorkbook.Connections
 If Left(cn, 13) = "Power Query -" Then cn.Refresh
 Next cn

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveSheet.SaveAs Filename:="customfile" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & ".txt", FileFormat:=xlTextWindows
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


 End Sub
```

now the issue I've been facing is that the refresh part and the save part work ok on their own, but if I put them in the same macro, the save part happens too soon, and the text file is empty. Can anyone help me ?

Thanks

Comment: There are a couple of different choices you have, though `DoEvents` should work. Look at this thread for the discussion [Wait until ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll finishes - VB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083668/wait-until-activeworkbook-refreshall-finishes-vba)

Comment: Thank you very much ! the DoEvent worked once i disabled the background refresh on the queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personnaly, I have choose to be a bit patient and added a timer to go on after a few seconds!

Try to add this in between :

```
DoEvents
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
DoEvents
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! the DoEvent worked once i disabled the background refresh on the queries

Comment: You are welcome! ;)
Plz accept answer (tick just under down vote) to close subject.