# How to wait for a Power Query refresh to finish?

Tags: excel, vba, refresh, powerquery, doevents

Setup:

- Windows 7 (at work)
- Windows 10 (at home)
- Excel 2016 (build 4627 at work)
- Excel 2016 (build 8730 at home)
- Power Query is setup to import, append, and transform a folder of Excel Files. This step works.

After using any technique to wait for a Power Query to finish refreshing as described in the "Things I have tried:" section shown below, a message box can be displayed and any other code can be executed before the Power Query tables have finished updating according to the refreshing indicator (spinner?) icon shown in the Queries and Connections pane.

The exception to the above statement is the `OnTime` method of the Application class, shown in the "Code" section below, which doesn't appear to interrupt the polling for a power query refresh. The problem is that it uses a hard coded amount of time to pause VBA code, and this will not always work since the size, amount, and duration of data being queried will change over time.

I tried:

- I have read all the StackOverflow (and other website resources) that state the use of the `DoEvents`, `BackgrgoundQuery = False`, and `CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone` methods and properties.
- I tried creating a class to [Create Before/After Query Update Events](http://www.excelandaccess.com/create-beforeafter-query-update-events/) as suggested at this link (not shown in the code example below).
- I tried using Do Until/While Loops with the .Refreshing = True/False property of the QueryTable method to wait for a refresh to finish.
- I tried setting the BackgroundQuery property in the Excel menu (menubar --> Data --> Connections --> Properties) to False as suggested by "subro" here: [Wait until ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll finishes - VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083668/wait-until-activeworkbook-refreshall-finishes-vba), with an image of the Menu here:

[image: Excel menu for setting the BackgroundQuery property].

Code:

```vb
Private Sub sht_sub_Refresh_AllConnections_dev()
    'Name: sht_sub_Refresh_AllConnections_dev
    'Purpose: An attempt at using VBA to wait for Queries to finish updating before displaying a message.
    'Description: Waits for a hard coded period of time before dislpaying the message box.
    'State: WIP.
    'Dev: Needs a way to look at the connection stream to somehow detect when its finished.
    
    'DECLARATIONS:
    '------------'
    Dim procName As String              'Stores this procedure's name.
    Dim qTblLst As QueryTables          'A query table collection object.
    Dim qTblObj As QueryTable           'A query table object.
    Dim conLst As Connections           'A connection collection object.
    Dim conObj As WorkbookConnection    'A connection object.
    Dim idx As Long                     'A loop counter.

    'INITIALIZATIONS:
    '---------------'
    procName = "sht_sub_Refresh_AllConnections_dev"    'Store this procedure's name.
    Linit.ini_Setup_Project                            'Setup the project if needed.
    Set conLst = ThisWorkbook.Connections              'Set the connections list object.
    Set conObj = conLst.Item(conLst.Count)             'Set an initial connection object.
    idx = 0                                            'As an exit if the do loop continues without end.
    
    'MAIN CODE BODY:
    '--------------'
    'Turn off backgroundquery for each connection type.
    For Each conObj In conLst                           'For each connection object,
        With conObj
            Select Case .Type                               'Check the connection type,
            Case 1                                        'If its an OLEDB connection then,
                .OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False    'Set it's backgroundquery property to false.
            Case 2                                        'If its an ODBC connection the,
                .ODBCConnection.BackgroundQuery = False     'Set it's backgroundquery property to false.
            End Select
        End With
    Next conObj
    
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll                             'Refresh all connections.
    
    'DEV: Using loops, DoEvents and a query name starting with the letters "zzzz" as suggsted here:
    'https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bc3f7748-8a52-498d-951c-4566b8adf45a/in-excel-2016-power-queries-dont-refresh-in-the-background-anymore?forum=powerquery
    'and here:
    'https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-forum/vba-macros/pause-macro-until-power-queries-finished-refreshing
    'Attempt to wait until the last connection has finished refreshing.
    Do Until Linit.gvTbl_ZZZZZ.QueryTable.Refreshing = True   'Wait until the last table starts refreshing,
        idx = idx + 1                                           'Icrement a loop count,
        If idx > 3000 Then Exit Do                              'If the loop goes longer then 3000 iterations exit,
    Loop                                                      'otherwise continue waiting.
    VBA.DoEvents                                              'Do events before continueing (doens't work).
    Do Until Linit.gvTbl_ZZZZZ.QueryTable.Refreshing = False  'Wait until the last table finishes refreshing,
        idx = idx + 1                                           'Icrement a loop count,
        If idx > 3000 Then Exit Do                              'If the loop goes longer then 3000 iterations exit,
    Loop                                                      'otherwise continue waiting.
    VBA.DoEvents                                              'Do events before continueing (doens't work).
    'DEV: The following is an attempt to get connections to
    '     finish refreshing before code continues as suggested here:
    'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083668/wait-until-activeworkbook-refreshall-finishes-vba
    Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone         'This is placed here as well as after the refresh.
    VBA.DoEvents                                              'Do events before continueing (doens't work).
    Application.EnableEvents = False                          'Maybe turning off events helps? (nope...),
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'This is reset in the procedure called as an argument to the next line:
    Application.OnTime DateAdd("s", 3, Now), _
                       "Lwksh.sht_sub_Msg_RefreshDone"        'The called procedure just displays a message box.
    Application.EnableEvents = True                           'Restore events,
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True                         'Restore screen updating.
    
    'MEMORY CLEANUP:
    '--------------'
EXIT_CLEAN:
    procName = Empty                                     
    Set qTblLst = Nothing
    Set qTblObj = Nothing
    Set conLst = Nothing
    Set conObj = Nothing
    idx = 0
End Sub
```

Code notes:

- Anything in the code preceded by "Linit." is an object or variable that is set globally outside the procedure by the "Linit.ini_Setup_Project" procedure call in the "INITIALIZATIONS:" section of the code.
- For example "Linit.gvTbl_ZZZZZ" is an object variable that points to an empty one row Table which has a name that stars with the characters "zzzz" and is generated by Power Query and loaded to an Excel sheet. The code shows the link to the website where the suggestion for using an empty table like this was made.

Questions:

1. Is this a lost cause due to Power Query not having a built in callback to let Excel know that it has finished updating any refresh processes?
2. If this is not a lost cause, is there any other way, not described here, that could be used to trigger an error to occur in some way if a connection has not yet finished refreshing, or to trigger the error when a connection is finished? (The thinking here being that this error could be trapped as a possible way of detecting weather or not the refresh has completed provided the error doesn't stop the query from finishing).
3. Is there any way to probe the connection stream directly using VBA to look for the connection closed or finished state?
4. Is there any way to directly access the refresh process via some call to a program outside of Excel written in some other language such as C# or Python?
5. Can you think of anything else that might be tried or tested to make this work? I'll keep searching for an answer on my own, but after a full year of searching I'm feeling a bit out of luck.

Comment: @ Mike: "TLDR" is understood. All the information is included in order to describe the problem completely which provides clarity to those who are willing to skim to get what they need from the question. Thank you for answering. I'll comment further under your post after making sure that what you've posted either works or still doesn't.

Comment: It is long, but IMHO clearly lists the problem, what you've tried, researched and coded so good job considering your new!

Answer (score 4):

I understand your pain @neurojelly. I have been there. But as it turns out the solution is quite simple and is not using VBA.
In the Query properties window, you need to **uncheck** the "Enable  background refresh" and then use `DoEvents`.
I know for sure this works as I have been using this method for over a year now.

Please find the link to a sample file that has the code in it. 
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1ZLxSMEXPLda3QhaQoTyGGv3_sC-tpN-X

[image: Disable background refresh]

As for your second question, it is possible to use `Iferror/OnEror` method's to detect if a query returns an error, but it doesn't necessarily check for errors in the query. It identifies if the query itself is returning an error pop-up which is skipped by default while running the VBA code. This method works most of the time, but not always.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround

```
Sub MyProcedure()

    '
    ' Some procedures
    '
    Call ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Call NotifyWhenRefreshComplete
End Sub



Private Sub NotifyWhenRefreshComplete()
    Const PulseTimer As Currency = TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Dim b1 As Boolean, b2 As Boolean

    b1 = Sheet1.Range("ListObject1").ListObject.QueryTable.Refreshing
    b2 = Sheet1.Range("ListObject2").ListObject.QueryTable.Refreshing

    If b1 Or b2 Then
        Call Application.OnTime(Now + PulseTimer, "NotifyWhenRefreshComplete")
    Else
        Call MsgBox("Refresh Complete.", vbOKOnly)
    End If
End Sub
```

ListObject1 and ListObject2 are published tables. Only published tables are necessary to check if refresh is complete. You don't have to check unpublished tables.

However If you have a lot of published tables, then there is no wrong to iterate through all `ActiveWorkbook.connections` and check if each and every `wbConn.OLEDBConnection.Refreshing` status has return to `false` state, replacing the `b1` and `b2` boolean.

Note: For some reasons,  I refuse to use the `DoEvents`, I want my users to be able to continue working with Excel while the connection is still running, and prompt them a message when the refresh is complete. But go ahead if you want to implement it with the `Do... Loop` iteration instead of the `OnTime` caller as shown above.

Lastly, there is a callback under `Public WithEvents qt As QueryTable`, look for `qt.refreshing`. You can use this method as well.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I'm calling the .Refresh method on ThisWorkbook.Connections.Ranges(1).ListObject.QueryTable, with BackgroundQuery:=False.  It seems quite reliable - by now my Macro has probably called that method over 10,000 times with a very low error/freeze rate.

As I understand it, all those DoEvents workarounds etc became obsolete when PQ was properly exposed in the object model for Excel 2016.

Here's a rough code sample:

```
Dim cn As WorkbookConnection
For Each cn In ThisWorkbook.Connections
    cn.Ranges(1).ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Next cn
```

Inside the For loop, you can examine cn.Name to control the execution of individual Queries.  The Name property follows the Workbook Connections names, e.g. "Query - " & PQ Query Name.

Comment: Its difficult to test if this works or not due to the following reason. The main table generated by the query in my code is dependent on a connection only query, and the code you've provided hangs with run-time error '-2147418113(8000ffff) "Method '_Default' of object 'Ranges' failed, on the line in the center of the For Each loop. Where the error only occurs on the connection only query in my test. My connection only query is a function that helps to make the sources for subsequent queries relative to the workbooks location. As such it can not be output to a table. Any advice?

Comment: Ok I've tested using a more static approach by just setting the one connection object that represents the table and using the same string as in the center of your for loop example. In my case its as follows: `conObj.Ranges(1).ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False` However code execution still continues while the refresh is still happening. In other words the spinner that shows in the query and connection pane is still spinning when the message box is displayed, and closed. Other cells in the workbook can also be selected while the refresh is still ongoing too.

Comment: I'll add the build version to my original post if this helps and if I'm allowed to do so. How are you testing whether or not your query is still refreshing with your example? Would you happen to know if the spinner that is shown on the Query and Connections pane is accurate enough to be trusted as an indicator of whether or not a refresh has completed successfully? Since your example didn't work, do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I just accept that I cant control the Excel UI, so if spinners want to spin they will. The code does work fine for me for the purpose - it executes the queries in series.  I show a MsgBox before and after to guide the user.

Comment: I am unable to determine if your solution works yet. There doesn't appear to be a verifiable way to test if a Query is in fact done refreshing. If VBA can execute before the query is finished, then would editing the query generated Table using VBA be an appropriate test? I'm not sure this wont result in false positives. For example, if a query only updates cells that need to be changed since the last refresh then a false positive could be possible. What do you think? How would you test this? What about changing the entire table, would that suffice as a good test?

Comment: Mike; Its all well and good that your Query refresh detection method has the appearance of working well for your purposes, but what about needing to do something in VBA with the data after its done refreshing? Such as standardizing the formatting of mailing addresses using corrective lists, or using VBA callable Excel add-ons, or maybe triggering some Event, or any number of other things the M Language makes more difficult or impossible to accomplish without the use of VBA. I'll see if VBA can edit an entire table before a refresh is finished.Hopefully this will be a good enough test.

Comment: I don't have any "Query refresh detection" - that doesn't seem necessary with Excel 2016. My VBA does some things after the For loop e.g. ThisWorkbook.SaveAs.  These all work reliably - further evidence that it just works and doesn't need to be overcomplicated.

Comment: I appreciate and value your input, but somehow I'm having a difficult time understanding your feedback. Every comment you have posted so far seems vague, at least from my point of view. For example, in our last comment, you state "These all work reliably - further evidence that it just works..." ...but how exactly is this evidence that it works. If code can continue before a refresh has finished then doesn't your SaveAs example just show that a SaveAs action can happen while a refresh hasn't finished yet?

Comment: I have seen evidence from over 10,000 executions that it works as I have described.  Where is your evidence that it doesn't?

Comment: I understand what your stating, and I'm not entirely in disagreement with you on this. The non-empirical argument that "it just works" is not something that can be tested. Nor is it something I can use to select as an answer to the question I have posted. The tests performed so far are not conclusive or definitive in answering my question. It is possible to watch 10,000 executions of a false positive result for an argument which is not constructive or instructive in any way. You claim that the spinners are a lie, but how can you tell?

Answer (score -1):

*********** SOLVED *************

PLEASE check you have activated ScreeUpdating. IT WORKED

```
Sub

...

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

tabla.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

Do While Application.CalculationState <> xlDone

DoEvents

Loop

...

End Sub
```