# Displaying each worksheet for 20 seconds and Refresh All

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code which works well to display each defined worksheet for 20 seconds, in a loop. I would like to be able to refresh the workbook after each loop or at a defined interval. Inserting ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll in the code doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Many thanks in advance

```
Sub Test2()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, t As Single, str As String
    Dim MyArray As Variant
    MyArray = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet4", "Sheet6")
    For j = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
        On Error GoTo exit_
        Application.EnableCancelKey = xlErrorHandler
        str = MyArray(j)
        Sheets(str).Select
        t = Timer + 1
        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 20)
        If Timer < t Then Exit Sub
        If j = UBound(MyArray) Then
            j = -1
        Else
            j = j
        End If
    Next j
exit_:

End Sub
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083668/wait-until-activeworkbook-refreshall-finishes-vba

Comment: Thank you @DecimalTurn - That was really helpful!

I added:

Activeworkbook.RefreshAll
DoEvents

  and disabled background refresh in my connections.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wait until ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll finishes - VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083668/wait-until-activeworkbook-refreshall-finishes-vba)

Comment: @DecimalTurn Yes it seems that the workbook refreshes before it goes to the next sheet instead of after the entire loop. I checked out the link you posted but still can't figure out how to do this. If you could provide any further insight, it would be much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, to do it at the end of one loop, you would have to put `ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll` and `DoEvents` right before `Next j`

Comment: @DecimalTurn - Apologies for the delayed response! I have just tried that but the refresh doesn't work at all. It just loops through all the sheets. Thanks again for the help :)

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you are really trying to do. Are you actually trying to refresh the sheet and let the user look at the refreshed sheet for 20 sec?

Comment: The workbook will be displayed on a screen in our office. There are 4 x sheets (with various reports) that we would like displayed for 20 seconds at a time (in a loop). We have several external data sources that require frequent refreshing. I hope this help explain - thanks again for your help on this

Comment: @DecimalTurn - apologies, I forgot to tag you in the above comment. Any insight would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you meant by "after the entire loop". If you want to show all 4 sheets (20 sec each) and then refresh, you would need to put it inside the if statement right after`j = -1`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to DecimalTurn's assistance, the following code worked after disabling background refresh:

```
Sub Test2()

 Dim i As Long, j As Long, t As Single, str As String
 Dim MyArray As Variant
 MyArray = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet4", "Sheet6")
 For j = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
    On Error GoTo exit_
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    DoEvents
    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlErrorHandler
    str = MyArray(j)
    Sheets(str).Select
    t = Timer + 1
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 20)
    If Timer < t Then Exit Sub
    If j = UBound(MyArray) Then
        j = -1
    Else
        j = j
    End If
Next j
exit_:

End Sub
```