# How to force VBA macros to wait for ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I've looked at the replies here : [old similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083668/wait-until-activeworkbook-refreshall-finishes-vba), tried everything but nothing worked.
I have tried:

1. Disabling the background refresh, problem here the execution time for individual queries takes forever.
2. Wait method, the wait method pauses the refresh all method which defeats the purpose.
3. I also tried after refresh but did not trigger it.

I have 71 power queries that runs on refresh all. The results for these queries are in hidden sheets, and I have one main sheet that contains links to  individual cells in the hidden sheets. As i mentioned all the remaining sheets are hidden.

There is no way so far to automate the entire experience after the refresh process. I have to intervene and do the work manually.

I need a way to tell VBA to not execute the following code until the refresh of all these queries and return their results.

Please Help!!

Comment: Maybe something along the lines of: `If Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then DoEvents`, would that work? If that doesn't work for you, maybe put it in a `Do Until` loop

Comment: Use: `Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone`

Comment: @Rory, that's the one =)

Comment: Thank you @JvdV, I am not sure if it would, I need more info on where should i insert this snippet of code?

Comment: Thanks a million @Rory, your suggestion is right on, I am able to trigger the refresh all method, and hold the  subsequent lines from executing until the refresh finalizes.