# Excel VBA not completing my code before next line

Tags: excel, vba

Hello there i have the following VBA in an excel sheet.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    Worksheets("BudgetInput").Unprotect Password:="password"
    Worksheets("BudgetInput").Range("G3:G150").Locked = True
    
    MsgBox "Sheet is now UnProtected"
   
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - MediaSubMedia").Refresh
    ActiveSheet.CircleInvalid
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - Media").Refresh
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - BudgetData").Refresh
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - TeamClients").Refresh
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - BaseVersionBudget").Refresh
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - F_Client_Grouping").Refresh
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - CurrVersionBudget").Refresh 
    MsgBox "Refresh Complete"
    
    Worksheets("BudgetInput").Range("G3:G150").Locked = False
    Worksheets("BudgetInput").Protect Password:="password"
    MsgBox "Sheet is now Protected"
End Sub
```

I have Message boxes to tell when each part completes.  But when i get to the last message, "Sheet is now protected" i get the following message.

The cell or chart you're trying to change is on a protected sheet. To make a change, un-protect the sheet.

It looks like the Refreshes are not completing before i protect my sheet.  Is there a way i can make sure my refreshes are complete, then run the code to protect my sheet.??

Kind Regards

Rob

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083668/wait-until-activeworkbook-refreshall-finishes-vba

Comment: https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-forum/vba-macros/pause-macro-until-power-queries-finished-refreshing

Comment: This worked for me

ActiveWorkbook.Save  forces the refreshing to complete before saving.

Answer (score -1):

Use this command -Application.Wait("0.010") before msgbox "refresh complete" to add wait time (eg 10seconds here) so that macro gets appropriate time to refresh. Hope this would work for you.