# VBA keeps skipping the refresh of data before saving; how do I fix this?

Tags: excel, vba, automation, odbc, reporting

I have a report that I'm trying to automate. All I need for it to do before saving is to refresh the data before saving to a specific path.I used a macro and pasted this in the vba before the save code:

**ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll**

And then there's also an application wait timer after that to make sure it loads in.

The strange thing is when I utilize F8 to manual go through each step of the code, the data refreshes just fine. It's just when I actually fully run it that it just skips that refresh and saves the empty report to the folder.

Some other notes:

I've got a **Dim sh1 As Worksheet** so I would've thought that I could do **sh1.RefreshAll** but I get a method error for that.

I also have a **Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("report")**

being that the name of the one tab is report. I don't know if including these couple of things helps in finding a solution.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. I'm pretty new to vba so I was limited to just using the macro to record the refresh all and then going from there.

Comment: If your queries are set to run in the background then your code will not wait for them to complete before hitting the Save line.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083668/wait-until-activeworkbook-refreshall-finishes-vba

Comment: How do I change it to not run in the background?

Comment: Did you look at the link I posted?