# How to refresh queries in sequence (refresh the next query until previous query is done refreshing)?

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to refresh my queries in sequence.
I recorded my Macro, but it turned out refresh all at the same time.
I'm not really familiar with VB.
Can some one please tell me is there any command can do so?
I tried to disable background refresh but that option is greyed out.

Here is the VB:
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - BOM").Refresh

```
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - Inventory").Refresh
 
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - IP vs non-IP").Refresh

ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - Priority").Refresh

ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - Relative_Priority").Refresh
 
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - InterCo_Priority_Table").Refresh
 
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - True Needs FIle").Refresh

ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - Promise_Dates").Refresh

ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - Sched_Ship_dates").Refresh

ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - Appended_Line_Down_Data").Refresh

ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - Top_to_Bottom").Refresh

ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - Backlogs - BOM").Refresh

ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - Backlogs").Refresh
```

Comment: @tlemaster you have linked *this* question rather than the one you intended.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083668/wait-until-activeworkbook-refreshall-finishes-vba