# Run Excel Macro using Power Automate Desktop

Tags: excel, vba, power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I am trying to Run an Excel Macro using Power Automate Desktop that refreshes all queries.

The problem is that power automate refuses to do it. I have watched every Youtube video about this topic, but can't seem to make it work.

Steps and Settings:

1. Launch excel

[image]

2. Run Excel Macro

[image]

3. Close excel

[image]

Macro:

```
Sub Refresh()

    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
```

[image]

I literally don't know what I am going wrong. The macro itself works.

I have tried playing around the name, including the Module name, workbook name, putting it in double, single, triple quotes, using ".", ";", "-" as delimiters etc.
Literally, what is wrong here? It's probably the easiest fix ever but, where exactly have I made a mistake?

Comment: Nothing wrong with what you have posted here. What do you mean by "power automate refuses to do it"? You could try isolating the issue by using a simpler macro like `MsgBox "hello world"`. What happens at the Run Excel macro step if you just run one action at a time. Do you really want to use `ActiveWorkbook` and not `ThisWorkbook`?

Comment: "power automate refuses to do it" = Doesn't run the macro, haha.... Ok, the hello world works... And you are right ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll was the problem. Now it runs the macro but closes the file instantly without waiting for the refresh to complete. Is there a better - a dynamic way to tell power automate to wait for the refresh than just using "Wait for 500seconds"? Maybe a macro that pops up a window, "table refreshed" after the table is refreshed and then closes the file?

Comment: It seems like Power Automate did run the macro, but the macro was acting on the wrong workbook. For the refresh, I think there are different methods depending on what type of queries you have, and also keep in mind `RefreshAll` refreshes more than just queries. Turning off `.BackgroundQuery` refresh is one method, as in the first answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083668/how-to-wait-until-activeworkbook-refreshall-finishes-before-executing-more-code

Comment: In the file there are queries, tables and pivot tables as well so, I am trying to refresh everything. Is it ok that I use the RefreshAll for this?