# .refresh BackgroundQuery:=False error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

i'm fighting with a problem..

i've got a VBA macro in excel 2013 (made in 2007 and worked fine in 2010)
it's scripted in SQL.
here is a bit of the code where the error is

```
 With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client 10.0;SERVER=APP14A\ISAHSERVER;UID=reader;PWD=reader;;DATABASE=ProduktieDB;", Destination _
        :=Range("$A$7")).QueryTable
        .CommandText = Array( _
        "SELECT T_DossierMain.OrdNr, T_DossierDetail.DetailCode, T_DossierDetail.Description, T_DossierDetail.PartCode, T_DossierDetail.CalcQty, T_DossierDetail.DiscPerc, T_DossierDetail.CurrPrice" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "FROM ProduktieDB.dbo.T_DossierDetail T_DossierDetail, ProduktieDB" _
        , _
        ".dbo.T_DossierMain T_DossierMain" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "WHERE T_DossierDetail.DossierCode = T_DossierMain.DossierCode AND ((T_DossierMain.OrdNr= '" & VariableOrderNo & "' ))" _
        )
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = False
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = False
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_Hoofdregels_Ophalen"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

End With

If IsEmpty(Range("A8").Value) Then
MsgBox "De order bestaat niet of heeft geen regels!"
Exit Sub
End If
```

so the problem is that i'm getting the error on the line ".refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
and if i remove that line, it will keep printing stuff

help?

regards,

michael

EDIT: i've found the problem.. this macro was made in 2007 so the only thing i had to do was changing the ".PreserveFormatting = False > True

thanks anyway =)

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/q/19916824/3130094

Comment: already tried alot from this website and nothing works